# Create a pdf from specific images programmatically

Tags: python, pdf

I would like to create a pdf that includes all .pngs that have a certain filename in them. Im not sure what language to try this in.
All my files are kept in a folder called Plots and this contains subfolders A, B etc. All the subfolders contain pngs called chr1.png,chr2.png, chrX.png etc. They are named the same in all subfolders. I would like to have a programme to create a pdf for all files with chr4.png from all of the subfolders. Can this be done in python?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`reportlab`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab) module for Python. It's fairly straightforward to generate simple PDF files, and all you'd have to do is loop through your file names, select based on your criteria, add each one to a new PDF page (or arrange them however you want), and generate the PDF.